# How to access polymorphic methods without a cast in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object, derived-class

```
class AlphaBase
{
    public bool PropA { get; set; }
}

class AlphaA : AlphaBase
{
    public bool PropB { get; set; }
}

class BetaBase
{
    protected AlphaBase MAlpha;
    public BetaBase(AlphaBase rAlpha)
    {
        MAlpha = rAlpha;
    }

}

class BetaA : BetaBase
{
    public BetaA(AlphaA rAlpha) : base(rAlpha) {}

    void DoSomething()
    {
        if (MAlpha.PropA) ;
        if (MAlpha.ProbB) ;  //wont compile
    }
}
```

Question: how do make this work, without creating a second variable for AlphA..

BetaBase will be using MAlpha and so will BetaB.. how do I achieve this without a cast and without 2 reference variables?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: Why can't you use a cast?  There is no way to invoke PropB from the base type because the base type AlphaBase has no knowledge of PropB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep your code type safe, you can make `BetaBase` generic as such:

```
class BetaBase<TAlphaBase>
    where TAlphaBase : AlphaBase
{
    protected TAlphaBase MAlpha;
    public BetaBase(TAlphaBase rAlpha)
    {
        MAlpha = rAlpha;
    }

}

class BetaA : BetaBase<AlphaA>
{
    public BetaA(AlphaA rAlpha) : base(rAlpha) {}

    void DoSomething()
    {
        if (MAlpha.PropA) ;
        if (MAlpha.PropB) ;  //yay! compiles now
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! no runtime overhead at all?

Comment: Generics are compiled to IL, it should be MUCH faster than cast with no perceivable performance hit at all.

Comment: damn - so there is a performance hit? Would it be faster creating a second reference to AlphaA inside BetaA?

Comment: @jaybny: no, there should be no performance hit using generics.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(MAlpha is AlphaA) {
    // You need to use a cast still
}
```

It's not possible to access properties of an object without a cast to that object. If you're just wanting to know if it's an instance of `AlphaA`, use the expression `... is AlphaA`.

Answer (score 0):

`MAlpha` is of type `AlphaBase`, which does not have a boolean property `PropB`.  You can only do this via cast.